# Clear shell screen everytime a shell command is run

Tags: terminal

Is there a way to clear the shell screen *everytime* before running a terminal command within vim?

This would be most useful to me when running scripts while editing it as I have a binding for Python scripts (for now; looking for a general solution though).

Currently I resort to `:!clear && !<command>` however I would like this to be automatic.

How can I do this. Maybe remap `!` to `!clear && !`?

**Update**:
So it turned out that I already had a solution in my vimrc for my specific case of running python scripts. I already had a `!clear` as part of the autocmd.

However, the question remains open for a general solution in which the screen is cleared before every terminal command executed particularly basic utilities like `grep` & `ls` which I prefer to execute in the terminal as I have color highlighting which is not present in vims' version.

Comment: Take a look at my answer here. It is not pure, it is a workaround.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61654295/7486926

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't do this with an `autocmd` since the only events that deal with shell commands occur *after* the command executes. I can't think of a better way to do it than your solution. We can't easily overwrite it with `command!` since `!` isn't a valid command name (It would also might not be wise to completely remap it), but we can use a `cabbrev`. Here's one way to do it:

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> ! (getcmdtype() == ':' && getcmdline() =~ '^!$')? '!clear && !' : '!'
```

- `getcmdtype() == ':'`: Only works in for an Ex command (not in searches for example).
- `getcmdline() =~ '^!$'`: Only works at the beginning of the command line.

See [`:help :cnoreabbrev`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Acnoreabbrev), [`:help getcmdtype()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getcmdtype%28%29), and [`:help getcmdline()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getcmdline%28%29) for more info.

Comment: I'm not sure, but some creative use of 'shell', 'shellcmdflag', or `t_ti`/`t_te` might work.